# Can I travel to Ireland with just my Convention 1951 refugee document?

Tags: visas, ireland, refugees

I have a refugee document issued by France. Can I travel to Ireland with this, or do I need a visa?

Comment: You need a visa from the ROI

Comment: Yes I'm on legal resident my mate.i obtained statue de refugee the convention of 1951.

Answer (score 14):

As France is not among the countries noted, per [The Republic of Ireland Naturalisation and Immigration Service](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Convention%20travel%20documents) (updated on 20 Jan 2017), you require a visa (emphasis mine):

> **Ireland accepts Convention travel documents issued by the countries listed below only**.
>
> Belgium, Czech Republic, Denmark, Finland, Germany, Hungary, Iceland, Italy, Liechtenstein, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Romania, Slovak Republic, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland.
>
> ***If you possess a Convention travel document issued by another country, you will require a visa***.

Comment: ... and the countries listed are exactly the current parties to the reciprocal [European Agreement on the Abolition of Visas for Refugees](https://www.coe.int/en/web/conventions/full-list/-/conventions/treaty/031). France used to be  a party but suspended their participation in 1986.